# How to update data in sql avoiding while loop for better performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I am updating data in while loop (in stored procedure) which is killing the performance badly. Is there any alternate (best) solution with relatively better performance while updating table.

I have read about CTE but not able to transform in my current problem

```
            WHILE (@Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @TopicsIds))
                 BEGIN
                   SELECT @CurrentTopicId = TopicId
                   FROM @TopicsIds
                   WHERE id = @Counter;
                   UPDATE @Modules
                  SET TopicId = @CurrentTopicId
                 WHERE id = @Counter;

                SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
                END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE m
SET TopicId = t.TopicId
FROM @Modules m
    JOIN @TopicsIds t ON m.Id = t.Id
```

Comment: defeated by fractions of seconds

Answer (score 0):

Why to use loop for update, use direct update query like

```
 update a set a.TopicId = b.TopicId
from @Modules as a
inner join @TopicsIds as b on a.id = b.id
```